# Flutter 2 Android - invoke method from native android to flutter when app is closed

Tags: android, flutter-plugin

I write flutter plugin for Android, and one fuctionality is to receive Firebase push messages. Plugin can receive push messages in native java code, show notification. But beside of this, I also need to invoke some flutter method when push message is received in native android. This also works fine when application running, but method is not invoked when app is in a background or closed (removed from recent apps).

Is this possible in flutter? Can I create MethodChannel in a FirebaseReceiver class or in a BroadcastReceiver?